# Android Switch/case

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, case

I've got this switch/case structure:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){

        case R.id.save:

            if (et.getText() !=null && thumbnail != null){

                 TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                 ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
                 TextView view2 = new TextView(this);
                 Button view3 = new Button(this);
                 view3.setOnClickListener(this);

                 titulo = new String[500];
                 mensaje = new String[500];
                 fotos = new Bitmap[500];

                 view3.setId(i);


                 view.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                 view.setPadding(1, 5, 0, 0);
                 view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

                 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

                 titulo[i]=""+et.getText();
                 mensaje[i]=""+et1.getText();
                 fotos[i]=thumbnail;
                 i++;

                 view2.setText("" + et.getText()  + dateFormat.format(c.getTime()) );
                 view2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                 view2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

                 view3.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                 view3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

                 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

                 tr.addView(view, metrics.widthPixels/3, 150);
                 tr.addView(view2, metrics.widthPixels/2, 100);
                 tr.addView(view3, metrics.widthPixels/6, 20);
                 tl.addView (tr, 0);


                 final Toast toastMensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Tu entrada se cargó correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toastMensaje.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toastMensaje.show();







                    et.setText("");
                    et1.setText("");
                    i1.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            }

            else{

                final Toast toastMensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Tienes que añadir un título y una foto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toastMensaje.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                toastMensaje.show();

            }


        break;

        case R.id.photo:

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);


        break;

        case R.id.gallery:

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
             startActivityForResult(intent, TFRequestCodes);

        break;

        case 0:

        final Toast toastMensaje = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   titulo[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toastMensaje.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toastMensaje.show();

            break;





    }

}
```

It works fine but i have to repeat the code for a long ammount of numbers from 0 to a number which depends on an array.lenght

Is there a way to reduce all that code?

Maybe a for loop, i've tried it but i cant make it work.

Thanks

Comment: You mean the switch cases are too many?

Comment: Yes, they are too many and they have to do "almost" the same. It only changes in the text that should be loaded in each case. So the code will be the same just changing de index of an array

Comment: Even if u use for loops, u will need same number of IF conditions.

Comment: instead of writing common onclick method you can write individual onclick listener to each component

Comment: if (id=1 || id=2 || id=3 || id=4.........|| id=n) -->StartActivity   (Where n is a int variable) What will change are the extras i've got to put. The buttons are created dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your `case 0` and following with:

```
    default:
        if (arg0.getId() < titulo.lenth) {
            final Toast toastMensaje = getToast(arg0.getId());
            toastMensaje.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toastMensaje.show();
        } else {
            //not a valid value
        }
        break;
}

private Toast getToast(int i) {
    return Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), titulo[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

Comment: Android switch case is same as Java Switch case, there is no difference.